# Wordpress Shortcode Function is displaying before content

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have been working on trying to get this shortcode to show correctly but everything I have tried does not work. Below is my function:

```
    function monster_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $monster = $atts['name'];

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'monsters',
        'name' => $monster,
    ));

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $monster_title = the_title();
    $monster_size = the_field('size');
    $monster_type = 'type';
    $monster_alignment = the_field( 'alignment' );
    $monster_ac = the_field( 'armor_class' );
    $monster_ac_type = the_field( 'ac_type' );
    $monster_hp = the_field( 'hit_points' );
    $monster_hd = the_field( 'hit_die' );
    $monster_speed = the_field( 'speed' );
    $monster_str = the_field( 'str' );
    $monster_strb = monster_stats( get_field( 'str' ) );
    $monster_dex = the_field( 'dex' );
    $monster_dexb = monster_stats( get_field( 'dex' ) );
    $monster_con = the_field( 'con' );
    $monster_conb = monster_stats( get_field( 'con' ) );
    $monster_int = the_field( 'int' );
    $monster_intb = monster_stats( get_field( 'int' ) );
    $monster_wis = the_field( 'wis' );
    $monster_wisb = monster_stats( get_field( 'wis' ) );
    $monster_cha = the_field( 'cha' );
    $monster_chab = monster_stats( get_field( 'cha' ) );
    $monster_saves = the_field( 'saving_throws' );
    $monster_skills = the_field( 'skills' );
    $monster_dmg = the_field( 'damage_adjustments' );
    $monster_senses = the_field( 'senses' );
    $monster_lang = the_field( 'languages' );
    $monster_cr = the_field( 'cr' );
    $monster_actions = the_field( 'actions' );
    $monster_reactions = the_field( 'reactions' );
    $monster_char = the_field( 'characteristics' );
    $monster_content = the_content();
    $monster_enviro = the_field( 'enviroments' );

    $return = '<h1 class="entry-title">' . $monster_title . '</h1>';
    $return .= '<div class="monster-meta">' . $monster_size . ' ' . $monster_type . ', ' . $monster_alignment . '</div>';
    $return .= '<ul class="monster-stat">';
        $return .= '<li><label>Armor Class</label> ' . $monster_ac . ' (' . $monster_ac_type . ')</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>Hit Points</label> ' . $monster_hp . ' (' . $monster_hd . ')</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>Speed</label> ' . $monster_speed . '</li>';
    $return .= '</ul>';
    $return .= '<ul class="monster-stat abilities">';
        $return .= '<li><label>STR</label>' . $monster_str . ' (' . $monster_strb . ')</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>DEX</label>' . $monster_dex . ' (' . $monster_dexb . ')</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>CON</label>' . $monster_con . ' (' . $monster_conb . ')</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>INT</label>' . $monster_int . ' (' . $monster_intb . ')</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>WIS</label>' . $monster_wis . ' (' . $monster_wisb . ')</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>CHA</label>' . $monster_cha . ' (' . $monster_chab . ')</li>';
    $return .= ' </ul>';
    $return .= '<ul class="monster-stat">';
        $return .= '<li><label>Saving Throws</label> ' . $monster_saves . '</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>Skills</label> ' . $monster_skills . '</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>Damage Adjustments</label> ' . $monster_dmg . '</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>Senses</label> ' . $monster_senses . '</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>Langauage</label> ' . $monster_lang . '</li>';
        $return .= '<li><label>Challenge Rating</label> ' . $monster_cr . '</li>';
    $return .= '</ul>';
    $return .= '<p>' . $monster_traits . '</p>';
    $return .= '<h4 class="monster-label">Actions</h2><p>' . $monster_actions . '</p>';
    $return .= '<h4 class="monster-label">Reactions</h2><p>' . $monster_reactions . '</p>';
    $return .= '<h4 class="monster-label">Characteristics</h2><p>' . $monster_char . '</p>';
    $return .= '<h4 class="monster-label">Details</h2><p>' . $monster_content . '</p>';               
    $return .= '<p><label>Enviroments:</label> ' . $monster_enviro . '</p>';

    endwhile;
    }
    return $return;
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
add_shortcode( 'monster', 'monster_shortcode' );
```

I then put the shortcode [monster name="men-at-arms"] on a page. All the function $variables show up before the post content and all the function html shows where it should be. You can see the output here https://www.dropbox.com/s/xvuqofya1jylsfl/Screenshot%20%283%29.png?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

You're using the **display** functions instead of the **return** functions.

[`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) will literally echo the title. If you want it as a variable, you need to use [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) (or you can set the third argument to `false` in `the_title()` - but that's generally not desirable)

This applies to all the functions you're using that are outputting a value.

`the_title()` => `get_the_title()`
[`the_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) => [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)
[`the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) => [`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content)

Since it's now pulling in the hosting post's content, you need to pass the ID from the shortcode to the functions. Either like so:

```
$monster    = $atts['name'];
$monster_id = $atts['id'];
   ...
$monster_title = get_the_title( $monster_id );
$monster_size  = get_field( 'size', $monster_id );
```

Or like so:

```
$monster    = $atts['name'];
   ...
$monster_title = get_the_title( $post->ID );
$monster_size  = get_field( 'size', $post->ID );
```

Alternatively, you can remove ALL the variable definitions and just modify the HTML returning portion.

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <div class="monster-meta"><?php the_field('size'); ?> <?php the_field('type'); ?> <?php the_field('alignment'); ?>
        <ul class="monster-stat">
         ...
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: This fixed it so now the data is in the template. However now it's pull the data from the post the shortcode is in instead of the shortcode data.

Comment: I've updated the answer - you either need to pass the ID to the functions: `get_the_title( $desired_id )`, or you can just remove all the variable definitions and place the original display functions in the HTML block

Comment: That works except I am not sure how to call the post id for the post that is being used in the shortcode. I only have the name that is entered into the shortcode when posting. But how do I get into the function?  I got it to show up by manually entering a post id, just to test if that was the issue.

Comment: Then it's probably easier to just use the second solution `$monster_title = get_the_title( $post->ID );` - This code: `while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();` should be setting `$post` (and thus `$post->ID` to the appropriate post for your HTML to use

Comment: Yea, something screwy is actually going on with your loops, because otherwise `get_the_title()` should work just fine without defining the id. Can you try renaming your `$query` to like `$monster_query` and see if that works?

Comment: This paste might help: https://pastebin.com/wyY8nzU9 - Note I modified a lot of it to reduce the number of times the `get_field` function is written out, so you can modify it easier and add new variables easier. Here's a commented one that explains what does what, and why: https://pastebin.com/EuhidrM7

(`$monster_traits` didn't seem to be defined in your original, and `type` was just a string, so I left traits alone and assumed `type` was supposed to be a `get_field` function.

Comment: That didn't change anything. I think I will just use the id in the shortcode instead. It works that way. Except the get_the_content( $monster_id ) is showing the current post content and not the shortcode post content.

Comment: I saw your post after I posted. Just tried it and it works! Just $monster_type = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'monster_type', '', ', ', '' ); was missing. I put it in but it doesn't show up. Probably the id problem.

Comment: I realized the problem after looking more at your code. I just changed $monster_type in the return to Just changed to " . $monster_type = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'monster_type', '', ', ', '' ) . " and that worked. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help!